# How to monkey-patch np.savez_compressed to add compression level, without editing numpy's source files?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compression, monkeypatching

I need to modify the ZIP `compressionlevel` internally used in [`np.savez_compressed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html). There is a [feature proposal](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20995) on Numpy Github, but it is not implemented yet.

I see two options:

- modify the source file `/numpy/lib/npyio.py` and replace `zipf = zipfile_factory(file, mode="w", compression=compression)` by  `<idem>..., compresslevel=compresslevel)`, but this creates the burden, that on each re-install or upgrade, after `pip install numpy`, I have to do this modification: this is a suboptimal solution.
- [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) the [`_savez` function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L713)

How to do this?

Here I tried the second option, but it fails with `ValueError: seek of closed file`, but I don't see why:

```
import numpy as np

def _savez(file, args, kwds, compress, allow_pickle=True, pickle_kwargs=None):
    import zipfile
    if not hasattr(file, 'write'):
        file = os_fspath(file)
        if not file.endswith('.npz'):
            file = file + '.npz'
    namedict = kwds
    for i, val in enumerate(args):
        key = 'arr_%d' % i
        if key in namedict.keys():
            raise ValueError("Cannot use un-named variables and keyword %s" % key)
        namedict[key] = val
    if compress:
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
    else:
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
    zipf = np.lib.npyio.zipfile_factory(file, mode="w", compression=compression, compresslevel=2)  # !! the only modified line !!
    for key, val in namedict.items():
        fname = key + '.npy'
        val = np.asanyarray(val)
        # always force zip64, gh-10776
        with zipf.open(fname, 'w', force_zip64=True) as fid:
            format.write_array(fid, val, allow_pickle=allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    zipf.close()

np.lib.npyio._savez = _savez    

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
with open("test.npz", "wb") as f:
    np.savez_compressed(f, x=x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ever simplier solution:

```
import numpy as np
def zipfile_factory(file, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(file, 'read'):
        file = os_fspath(file)
    import zipfile
    kwargs['allowZip64'] = True
    kwargs['compresslevel'] = 4
    return zipfile.ZipFile(file, *args, **kwargs)
np.lib.npyio.zipfile_factory = zipfile_factory
with open("test.npz", "wb") as f:
    np.savez_compressed(f, x=np.ones(10_000_000))
```

---

**Edit**: old solution:

I found the solution in the meantime: `format` should be replaced by `np.lib.npyio.format`. Now this works:

```
import numpy as np

def _savez(file, args, kwds, compress, allow_pickle=True, pickle_kwargs=None):
    import zipfile
    if not hasattr(file, 'write'):
        file = os_fspath(file)
        if not file.endswith('.npz'):
            file = file + '.npz'
    namedict = kwds
    for i, val in enumerate(args):
        key = 'arr_%d' % i
        if key in namedict.keys():
            raise ValueError("Cannot use un-named variables and keyword %s" % key)
        namedict[key] = val
    if compress:
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
    else:
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
    zipf = np.lib.npyio.zipfile_factory(file, mode="w", compression=compression, compresslevel=1)
    for key, val in namedict.items():
        fname = key + '.npy'
        val = np.asanyarray(val)
        # always force zip64, gh-10776
        with zipf.open(fname, 'w', force_zip64=True) as fid:
            np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(fid, val, allow_pickle=allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    zipf.close()

np.lib.npyio._savez = _savez    

with open("test.npz", "wb") as f:
    np.savez_compressed(f, x=np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```